# How can I access to the attributes of an object of a class?

Tags: python, object, oop, attributes, memory-address

I have the following code:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, age, name) -> None:
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
    
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age
    
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    
class Animals:
    def __init__(self, index) -> None:
            self.index = index
            self.animalList = None
    
    def startInsert(self):
        newTable = list()
        for i in range(self.index):
            newTable.append(None)
        self.animalList = newTable
        
    def insertInIndex(self, index, animalObject):
        for i in range(len(self.animalList)):
            if i == index:
                self.animalList[i] = animalObject
    
    def show(this):
        for i in range(len(this.animalList)):
            if this.animalList[i] is not None:
                print('index: ',i,', Age: ',this.animalList[i].getAge,', Name: ',this.animalList[i].getAge)

animals = Animals(5)
animals.startInsert()
cow = Animal(2, "Cow")
dog = Animal(3, "Dog")
animals.insertInIndex(2, cow)
animals.insertInIndex(3, dog)
animals.show()
```

I want to send an object `Animal` to my list `animalList` which one is part of the`Animals` class

My problem is that I can not access to the `Age` and `Name` attributes of my `Animal` class from my `Animals` class

My expected output is:

```
index: 2, Age: 2, Type: Cow
index: 3, Age: 3, Type: Dog
```

What I have done is:

```
def show(this):
        for i in range(len(this.animalList)):
            if this.animalList[i] is not None:
                print('index: ',i,', Age: ',this.animalList[i].getAge,', Name: ',this.animalList[i].getAge)
```

But my console just shows the next memory addresses:

```
index:  2 , Age:  <bound method Animal.getAge of <__main__.Animal object at 0x00000200ead03cd0>> , Type:  <bound method Animal.getAge of <__main__.Animal object at 0x00000200ead03cd0>>
index:  3 , Age:  <bound method Animal.getAge of <__main__.Animal object at 0x00000200ead03c70>> , Type:  <bound method Animal.getAge of <__main__.Animal object at 0x00000200ead03c70>>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is python not java. You don't need a getter like `getAge()` just use `this.animalList[i].age`, etc. If you do go that way, you need to call the function with `this.animalList[i].getAge()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
print('index: ',i,', Age: ',this.animalList[i].getAge,', Name: ',this.animalList[i].getAge)
```

You are printing `this.animalList[i].getAge`, which is a function. To actually get the age, you must call the function like `this.animalList[i].getAge()`.

This alone will resolve the question, however, your question has a few other (minor) issues. In the code below, I have removed your getter functions (which are unnecessary and are causing you confusion), corrected indentation, and refactored some code to make it look better. I also removed the `animals.startInsert` method, as it should be part of the constructor. I hope this helps you understand better:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, age, name) -> None:
        self.age = age
        self.name = name


class Animals:
    def __init__(self, index) -> None:
        self.index = index
        self.animalList = [None for i in range(index)]

    def insertInIndex(self, index, animalObject):
        self.animalList[index] = animalObject

    def show(self):
        for i in range(len(self.animalList)):
            if self.animalList[i] is not None:
                print('index: ', i, ', Age: ', self.animalList[i].age,
                      ', Name: ', self.animalList[i].age)


animals = Animals(5)
cow = Animal(2, "Cow")
dog = Animal(3, "Dog")
animals.insertInIndex(2, cow)
animals.insertInIndex(3, dog)
animals.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, getters are unnecessary  just in python? or in any languages?

Comment: @asker In some languages, using getters is the best practice. However, in python, it is better to directly use properties, as python does not have the distinction between private and public properties.